# jqXHR vs. jQuery AJAX-requests in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqxhr

I don't understand why this jQuery.AJAX-request to a .csv-file fails to display a Highchart chart in Rails:

```
var jQuery = $.get('foo.csv', function(data) {}
```

whereas this one displays just fine:

```
var jqxhr = $.get('foo.csv', function(data) {}
```

Can anybody please explain?

Comment: Cheers. Now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery` is the name of the main function in the jQuery library (`$` is just a synonym for it). You shouldn't reuse it in your own code. Although if this is a local variable, I don't think it should affect the library, it uses the global variable `window.jQuery`. But it's still a bad idea to use this variable name, it will be confusing.

Comment: OK I got it. Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

The only difference here is the name of your variable – perhaps `jQuery` is just a reserved word?